# How to make a TPanel's appearance smoother when it is being dragged?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, vcl

I want to make a `TPanel` draggable. I have done so, but the panel looks jerky when it is being dragged. How can I make it smoother?

Perhaps you don't have to look at my code to answer that, but here it is, just in case:

```
unit fMainForm;
interface

uses
Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
TtheMainForm = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
  FDragging: Boolean;
  FDragStartPos: TPoint;
  FDragPanel: TPanel; // the panel being dragged

  procedure AddLocation(const name : String);
  procedure PanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  procedure PanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  procedure PanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var theMainForm: TtheMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TtheMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddLocation('New');
end;

procedure TtheMainForm.AddLocation(const name: String);
var newPanel : TPanel;
begin
  newPanel := TPanel.Create(theMainForm);
  newPanel.Parent := theMainForm;
  newPanel.Name := name;
  newPanel.Caption := name;
  newPanel.Color := clBtnFace; // Set to a specific color to cause opacity when fdragging   to look smoother
  newPanel.ParentBackground := False;  // helps to reduce flicker

  newPanel.OnMouseDown := PanelMouseDown;
  newPanel.OnMouseMove := PanelMouseMove;
  newPanel.OnMouseUp := PanelMouseUp;
end;   // AddLocation()

procedure TtheMainForm.PanelMouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if Sender is TPanel then
  begin
    FDragPanel := TPanel(Sender);
    FDragging := True;
    FDragStartPos := Point(X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TtheMainForm.PanelMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var DeltaX, DeltaY: Integer;
begin
  if FDragging and (FDragPanel <> nil) then
  begin
    DeltaX := X - FDragStartPos.X;
    DeltaY := Y - FDragStartPos.Y;

    FDragPanel.Left := FDragPanel.Left + DeltaX;
    FDragPanel.Top := FDragPanel.Top + DeltaY;

    FDragStartPos := Point(X, Y);
  end;
end;

procedure TtheMainForm.PanelMouseUp(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  FDragging := False;
  FDragPanel := nil; // Reset the dragged panel
end;

end.
```

Please note that I must create my panels dynamically at run-time. This code creates a single panel. <kbd>Ctrl-click</kbd> it to grab it, move the mouse/trackpad to drag the panel, and release to end the drag.

The appearance when dragging doesn't really seem acceptable to me. How can I make it smoother?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `WMNcHitTest` to make it draggable?

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of the `FDragStartPos := Point(X, Y);` at the bottom of `PanelMouseMove`.

Comment: If the contents and size won't change while it is being dragged around, you could also move around a temporary bitmap of the panel. To reduce text flicker in your example can also add `newPanel.DoubleBuffered := true;`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't read the full code. Yes, as @Brian points out, you are actually comparing the initial position with the final one (no differential deltas), so `FDragStartPos´ should indeed not be set in the mouse move handler.

Comment: And add a test to make sure that only the right mouse button (=the left one) can begin a move operation.

Comment: But I still prefer the `WMNcHitTest` approach: `procedure TPanel.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  Message.Result := HTCAPTION;
end;` and you are done.

Comment: @Brian  that has made it perfectly smooth. Thank you. If you post an answer, I will award it. If things slow down again, I will try out some of the other suggestions. Thank you, all

Comment: IMHO an answer isn't needed since the issue was caused by a trivial error of thought. It's unlikely such a Q&A will help future Stack Overflow users.

Comment: So, I ought to delete the question?

Comment: I think that's what I'd do, yes.